# How to Reset Time of an analog clock by dragging it's handles C#

Tags: c#

I'm very new to C#, the aim here is to edit the Time of an analog Clock by dragging it's handles.  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Analog-Clock-Control-0e8ffcab#content this code has inpired me. I have three simple functions MouseDown, MouseMove and MouseUp but still I can not get Drag to work. Any suggestions please ?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
#region Construct the clock 

public Point Start { get; set; }
public Point End { get; set; }

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DoubleBuffered = true;

    //Create the timer and start it 
    ClockTimer.Tick += ClockTimer_Tick;
    ClockTimer.Enabled = true;
    ClockTimer.Interval = 1;
    ClockTimer.Start();
    Start = p1;
    End = p2;
}
#endregion

#region Update the clock 

private void ClockTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Refresh();
}

private Timer ClockTimer = new Timer();
private Pen circle = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
private Pen secondHandle = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
private Pen minHandle = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
private Pen hrHandle = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);

private Point p1;
private Point p2;

#endregion

#region On paint 

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
    base.OnPaint(pe);

    //Clear the graphics to the back color of the control 
    pe.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);

    //Draw the border of the clock 
    pe.Graphics.DrawEllipse(circle, 0, 0, 300, 300);

    //Find the radius of the control by dividing the width by 2 
    float radius = (300 / 2);

    //Find the origin of the circle by dividing the width and height of the control 
    PointF origin = new PointF(300 / 2, 300 / 2);

    //Draw only if ShowMajorSegments is true; 
    if (ShowMajorSegments)
    {
        //Draw the Major segments for the clock 
        for (float i = 0f; i != 390f; i += 30f)
        {
            pe.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.White, PointOnCircle(radius - 1, i, origin), PointOnCircle(radius - 21, i, origin));
        }
    }

    //Draw only if ShowMinorSegments is true 
    if (ShowMinorSegments)
    {
        //Draw the minor segments for the control 
        for (float i = 0f; i != 366f; i += 6f)
        {
            pe.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, PointOnCircle(radius, i, origin), PointOnCircle(radius - 10, i, origin));
        }
    }

    //Draw only if ShowSecondHand is true 
    if (ShowSecondhand)
        //Draw the second hand 
        pe.Graphics.DrawLine(secondHandle, origin, PointOnCircle(radius, DateTime.Now.Second * 6f, origin));


    //Draw only if ShowMinuteHand is true 
    if (ShowMinuteHand)
        //Draw the minute hand 
        pe.Graphics.DrawLine(minHandle, origin, PointOnCircle(radius * 0.75f, DateTime.Now.Minute * 6f, origin));
        minHandle.StartCap = LineCap.RoundAnchor;
        minHandle.EndCap = LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
        pe.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.High;
        pe.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;


    //Draw only if ShowHourHand is true 
    if (ShowHourHand)
        //Draw the hour hand 
        pe.Graphics.DrawLine(hrHandle, origin, PointOnCircle(radius * 0.50f, DateTime.Now.Hour * 30f, origin));
        hrHandle.StartCap = LineCap.RoundAnchor;
        hrHandle.EndCap = LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
        pe.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.High;
        pe.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;


}
#endregion

#region On size changed 

protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSizeChanged(e);

    //Make sure the control is square 
    if (Size.Height != Size.Width)
        Size = new Size(Size.Width, Size.Width);

    //Redraw the control 
    Refresh();
}
#endregion

#region Point on circle 

private PointF PointOnCircle(float radius, float angleInDegrees, PointF origin)
{
    //Find the x and y using the parametric equation for a circle 
    float x = (float)(radius * Math.Cos((angleInDegrees - 90f) * Math.PI / 180F)) + origin.X;
    float y = (float)(radius * Math.Sin((angleInDegrees - 90f) * Math.PI / 180F)) + origin.Y;

    return new PointF(x, y);
}
#endregion

#region Show Minor Segments 

private bool showMinorSegments = true;

public bool ShowMinorSegments
{
    get
    {
        return showMinorSegments;
    }
    set
    {
        showMinorSegments = value;
        Refresh();
    }
}
#endregion

#region Show Major Segments 

private bool showMajorSegments = true;

public bool ShowMajorSegments
{
    get
    {
        return showMajorSegments;
    }
    set
    {
        showMajorSegments = value;
        Refresh();
    }
}
#endregion

#region Show Second Hand 

private bool showSecondHand = false;

public bool ShowSecondhand
{
    get
    {
        return showSecondHand;
    }
    set
    {
        showSecondHand = value;
        Refresh();
    }
}
#endregion

#region Show Minute Hand 

private bool showMinuteHand = true;

public bool ShowMinuteHand
{
    get
    {
        return showMinuteHand;
    }
    set
    {
        showMinuteHand = value;
        Refresh();
    }
}
#endregion

#region Show Hour Hand 

private bool showHourHand = true;

public bool ShowHourHand
{
    get
    {
        return showHourHand;
    }
    set
    {
        showHourHand = value;
        Refresh();
    }
}
#endregion

public float slope
{
    get
    {
        return (((float)p2.Y - (float)p1.Y) / ((float)p2.X - (float)p1.X));
    }
}
public float YIntercept
{
    get
    {
        return p1.Y - slope * p1.X;
    }
}

public bool IsPointOnLine(Point p, int cushion)
{
    float temp = (slope * p.X + YIntercept);
    if (temp >= (p.Y - cushion) && temp <= (p.Y + cushion))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

Point deltaStart;
Point deltaEnd;
bool dragging = false;

private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left  && IsPointOnLine(e.Location, 5))
    {
        dragging = true;
        deltaStart = new Point(p1.X - e.Location.X, p1.Y - e.Location.Y);
        deltaEnd = new Point(p2.X - e.Location.X, p2.Y - e.Location.Y);
    }
}

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (dragging && deltaStart != null && deltaEnd != null)
    {
        p1 = new Point(deltaStart.X + e.Location.X, deltaStart.Y + e.Location.Y);
        p2 = new Point(deltaEnd.X + e.Location.X, deltaEnd.Y + e.Location.Y);
        this.Refresh();
    }
}

private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    dragging = false;
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "but still I can not get Drag to work"? Your drawing is based on `DateTime.Now` and the `Start` and `End` variable are largely unused. Please be more specific on what you want. A good starting point may be to determine the angle of the point where your mouse currently is at `Form1_MouseMove` and to draw an additional line based on that angle.

Comment: Thanks grek40 for your reply, I have edited my question implementing your suggestions about making use of `Start` and `End` variables but I'm having slight difficulties to determine the angle of the point where the mouse is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give a partial answer about translating a `X`, `Y` coordinate to an angle (in degree) based on a circle, where the `0°` angle is located at the top.

*(Scroll down for a compact solution)*

Following the directions of typical GUI coordinates, the absolute 0,0 Point is located top left, positive X values stretch to the right and positive Y values stretch to the bottom.

In order to simplify the math, I use a virtual 0,0 point at the center of the circle, so all coordinates need to be translated to locals before calculation and to globals before actual drawing.

Coordinate overview (imagine the circle around `0; 0`):

```
          (0;-1)


(-1; 0)   (0; 0)    (1; 0)


          (0; 1)
```

Now the task is for any coordinate `(X; Y)` to find the clock-wise angle between the line `(0; 0) - (0; -1)` and the line `(0; 0) - (X; Y)`

The circle can be divided into 4 quarter-circles, each covering a combination of signed `(X; Y)` values.

**Quarter 1** contains the angle values `0°` to `90°` and is represented by positive `X` values and negative `Y` values.

**Quarter 2** contains the angle values `90°` to `180°` and is represented by positive `X` values and positive `Y` values.

**Quarter 3** contains the angle values `180°` to `270°` and is represented by negative `X` values and positive `Y` values.

**Quarter 4** contains the angle values `270°` to `360°` and is represented by negative `X` values and negative `Y` values.

Note that for the corner cases `0°`, `90°`, `180°`, `270°`, `360°` it doesn't really matter which of the two quarters they are assigned to.

The easiest way to understand such problems is to stick to the normal circle -> read: to normalize the `X; Y` coordinate to a length of `1`. Additionally I go with positive values (it would also work without, but a bit differently in the `+` and `-` combinations):

```
var len = Math.Sqrt(X * X + Y * Y);
var xNorm = Math.Abs(X) / len;
var yNorm = Math.Abs(Y) / len;
```

Now, the reverse sine / cosine can be used to translate the normalized coordinates back into angle values (there's some redundancy in my calculation for the sake of simplicity and completeness):

```
var angleFromX = Math.Asin(xNorm) * 180.0 / Math.PI;
var angleFromY = Math.Asin(yNorm) * 180.0 / Math.PI;
```

Now lets apply the appropriate angle for each of the quarter circle areas

```
var resultAngle = 0.0;
if (quarter_1)
{
    resultAngle = 0 + angleFromX;
    // same as
    resultAngle = 90 - angleFromY;
}
if (quarter_2)
{
    resultAngle = 90 + angleFromY;
    // same as
    resultAngle = 180 - angleFromX;
}
if (quarter_3)
{
    resultAngle = 180 + angleFromX;
    // same as
    resultAngle = 270 - angleFromY;
}
if (quarter_4)
{
    resultAngle = 270 + angleFromY;
    // same as
    resultAngle = 360 - angleFromX;
}
```

Ofcourse, the `quarter_1` - `quarter_4` are pseudo-variables that represent the quarter selection as explained.

---

A more compact solution can be found by analyzing the different properties of the full solution.

```
var angleFromYAxis = Math.Asin(Y / Math.Sqrt(X * X + Y * Y)) * 180.0 / Math.PI;

var resultAngle = 0.0;
if (X >= 0)
{
    resultAngle = 90 + angleFromYAxis;
}
else
{
    resultAngle = 270 - angleFromYAxis;
}
```